# Problems with custom villagers and trading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Just a heads up, if I seem inexperienced in typing my question in a certain style, please forgive me!

I used a command generator, from [this link](https://minecraftcommand.science/shop-generator), to spawn a villager who sells custom weapons.

However, the generator does not support villagers selling custom WEAPONS, only custom ITEMS. That means I have to enter the values myself, given the format provided. I have 2 more of such commands and they work perfectly fine, but only this one has a persistent problem.

Anyway, I wish to spawn a villager that trades 8 nether stars and 1 diamond for a custom pickaxe weapon, but the result was shown in the picture attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVuk1.png).

This is the whole command:

```
/summon Villager ~1 ~ ~ {Profession:0,CustomName:"The Shop Elf #3",CustomNameVisible:1,Career:1,CareerLevel:42,CanPickUpLoot:0,PersistenceRequired:1,Invulnerable:1,Attributes:\[{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:"1f"},{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:"0f"},{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:99999}\],Offers:{Recipes:\[{buy:{id:"nether_star",Count:5},buyB:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"golden_hoe",Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"The Lucky Golden Scythe",Lore:\["Is that really gold... or just children's glitter?","You get more resources by slaying mobs."\]},ench:\[{id:16,lvl:3},{id:21,lvl:3},{id:34,lvl:2},{id:35,lvl:5}\]},MaxUses:9999999},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"nether_star",Count:7},buyB:{id:"dye",Count:1,Damage:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"golden_hoe",Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Mace of Tarrasque",Lore:\["Preserves the blood of an extinct monster.","Boosts your health dramatically."\]},AttributeModifiers:\[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:50,Operation:0,UUIDMost:30803,UUIDLeast:806745},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:1,Operation:1,UUIDMost:34336,UUIDLeast:736873}\],ench:\[{id:16,lvl:1},{id:19,lvl:3},{id:21,lvl:1},{id:34,lvl:5},{id:35,lvl:1}\]},MaxUses:9999999},rewardExp:false},{buy:{id:"nether_star",Count:8},buyB:{id:"diamond",Count:1, maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"diamond_pickaxe",Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Sapphire Daedalus",Lore:\["The second most powerful weapon of the land.","Extremely high damage and health."\]},AttributeModifiers:\[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:35,Operation:0,UUIDMost:90871,UUIDLeast:499725},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:0,Operation:0,UUIDMost:66479,UUIDLeast:426152}\],ench:\[{id:16,lvl:5},{id:17,lvl:5},{id:18,lvl:5},{id:19,lvl:5},{id:20,lvl:5},{id:21,lvl:1},{id:34,lvl:1},{id:35,lvl:1}\]},MaxUses:9999999},rewardExp:false}}]}}
```

and this is the part of the command responsible for summoning the desired custom pickaxe:

```
{buy:{id:"nether_star",Count:8},buyB:{id:"diamond",Count:1, maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"diamond_pickaxe",Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Sapphire Daedalus",Lore:["The second most powerful weapon of the land.","Extremely high damage and health."]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:35,Operation:0,UUIDMost:90871,UUIDLeast:499725},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:0,Operation:0,UUIDMost:66479,UUIDLeast:426152}],ench:[{id:16,lvl:5},{id:17,lvl:5},{id:18,lvl:5},{id:19,lvl:5},{id:20,lvl:5},{id:21,lvl:1},{id:34,lvl:1},{id:35,lvl:1}]},MaxUses:9999999},rewardExp:false}}]}}
```

There must be a reason why the pickaxe doesn't appear in the trade menu, and I don't think it's a bug. I hope any experts on Minecraft data tagging could help me out; I would be really grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Your `sell` tag is inside the `buyB` compound tag.

```
...buyB:{id:"diamond",Count:1, maxUses:9999999,sell:{...
```

You'll need to close the `buyB` tag after `Count`. Note that this probably means you have to remove a closing curly bracket somewhere else, lest you get unbalanced brackets.

There's also an additional `maxUses` tag inside sell, which doesn't do anything. Here's the fixed compound tag for that particular trade:

```
{buy:{id:"nether_star",Count:8},buyB:{id:"diamond",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"diamond_pickaxe",Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Sapphire Daedalus",Lore:["The second most powerful weapon of the land.","Extremely high damage and health."]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:35,Operation:0,UUIDMost:90871,UUIDLeast:499725},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:0,Operation:0,UUIDMost:66479,UUIDLeast:426152}],ench:[{id:16,lvl:5},{id:17,lvl:5},{id:18,lvl:5},{id:19,lvl:5},{id:20,lvl:5},{id:21,lvl:1},{id:34,lvl:1},{id:35,lvl:1}]},},rewardExp:false}
```

When inserting it into your command, make sure to correctly close all brackets. It should be `]}}` after this to Close the `Recipes` list, close `Offers`, close the whole thing.